# Best hypervisor for nfv in terms of throughput

Tags: openstack, esxi, hypervisor

I am trying to find out what is the best hypervisor to run NFV (Network Functions Virtualization) solutions. I am particularly interested in KVM and ESXi. Could somebody help out in selecting the best hypervisor for NFV components in terms of performance/throuhput?

Answer (score 0):

if you are considering kvm, then using SRIOV or dpdk-ovs might be good solution.

https://wiki.opnfv.org/nfv_hypervisors-kvm